# Pyspark Dataframe read is shifting column contents by inconsistent number

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Code Versions:

- Python==3.7
- Spark Version==2.4.7
- Pyspark==2.4.5
- Hive==2.3.7

Hello, hoping someone can help me with this.
I'm using PySpark to read several large files (around 80 GB each,  6 or so of them).
Using one leader node, two worker nodes.

The file being read has over 1000 cols, and has millions on millions of rows.  When I try to process this file with the pyspark read function, it pushes out column values by an inconsistent number of columns.

Things I have tried:

1. Looked at number of delimiters on each row.  This number appears to be consistent across rows, but I've only looked at one file.
2. Tried fixed width for each col by using `read.text(s3_path)` and using substr for each column.  This did not work.
3. Tried to infer nulls from empty strings `.option("emptyValue", '')`
4. When I try to look at the raw data from the CSV, I do not see unescaped quotes or `\t` in it.  Reading problematic rows in pandas reads correctly...

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


Class SparkCode:
    def __init__(self):
       self.session = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").getOrCreate()
       self.schema = StructType().add

    def process_file(self, s3_bucket, s3_key):
        s3_path = f's3a://{s3_bucket}/{s3_key}'

        df_reader = self.session.read

        responses = df_reader.option("delimiter", "\t") \
            .csv(s3_path) \
            .select(
                    col('_c5').alias("state").cast(StringType()),
                    col('_c6').alias("zip_code").cast(StringType()),
                    col('_c7').alias("zip_plus_4").cast(StringType()),
                    col('_c8').alias("carrier_route").cast(StringType()),
                    col('_c9').alias("county_code").cast(StringType()),
                    col('_c10').alias("county_name").cast(StringType()),
                    col('_c11').alias("phone_number").cast(StringType()),
...
                    col('_c745').alias("another_important_col").cast(StringType()))
        responses.show()
        responses.select("all_the_above_cols").write.mode("append").parquet("s3a://other_s3_path" + ".parquet/")
```

Question:  given that investigating each problematic row takes a long time, what can I do to improve the above code to parse these data correctly?  Any suggestions or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you could try out.

1. If you are opening your csv file in Excel and checking and you don't see any issues then try to open it in notepad++ and see if you see any differences. Sometimes if there is something odd in csv files and if we open in excel we don't come to know about it.
2. See your csv files has any column whose value can be multiline. If you find anything then you can add an `option("multiline","true")` and see if that works.
3. If there are any quotes or escape strings in your data that might be causing the issue then you could add two more options to see if it works. i.e `.option("quote", "\"")` and `.option("escape", "\"")`

I had similar issue and got around by adding this extra options to the reader and it worked fine.

Comment: extracted the raw data into  a separate file.  When opening the raw data using pandas, the error doesn't appear.  My guess is that this problem is a part of spark csv reading...

Comment: problem might be because of spark but for some special cases you need to provide various option for it to work. The default read option does not cover all the use cases.

Comment: I have the same problem, the data I have was text data and the similar issue I have faced, but using quote, escape and multiline options as suggested by @NikunjKakadiya my data  looks good for further processing.